# Apexchart does not update dynamically using axios

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, apexcharts

The updateSeries function does not seem to work. I can't find out why it doesn't though. The uChart() function does indeed get called. I have the following code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <Menu></Menu>
    <h1> Our Home Website! </h1>

    <apexchart ref="chart1" width="500" type="line" :options="options" :series="series"></apexchart>
</div>
```

import Menu from './Menu'
    import axios from 'axios'

```
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: {
        'Menu': Menu
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    height: 350,
                    type: 'bar',
                    id: 'chart'
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [],
                title: {
                    text: 'Ajax Example',
                },
                noData: {
                    text: 'Loading...'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.uChart()
    },
    methods: {
        uChart: function() {
            axios
                .get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/yearly')
                .then(function (response) {
                    this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{
                        name: 'Sales',
                        data: response.data
                    }])
                });
            console.log(this.$refs.chart1);
        }
    }
```

The reference to the chart works as well as the link for the JSON data. But the chart remains on the "loading" state.:
[This is how it actually looks like on the website and the errors that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4r9.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: TL;DR: `then` argument is a callback and should be an arrow.

Comment: Yes, this helped. Thank you.
I wrote changed the then() function to this syntax: .then(response => {...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Estus Flask mentioned in his comment. The answer to this question is to use the arrow syntax for the "then" argument because it is a callback. Therefore the correct function looks like this:

```
    methods: {
    uChart: function() {
        axios
            .get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/yearly')
            .then(response => {
                this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{
                    name: 'Sales',
                    data: response.data
                }])
            });
        console.log(this.$refs.chart1);
    }
}
```

For further details around this topic check the answer to this question:
[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)