# Apexchats.js axios gives me undefined with Vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, apexcharts

I am trying to get data from server using `vue` and `apexcharts`, but even after I called data with `axios`, it gives me `undefined`..

What have I missed?

template

```js
<apexchart
  ref="chart1"
  width="100%"
  :options="chartOptions" :series="series">
</apexchart>
```

data from url

```json
{
    "pageviews": 1313,
    "new_users": 1014
}
```

script

```js
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            series: [],
            chartOptions: {
             chart: {
               type: 'donut',
             }, 
            colors: ['#01cd49', '#007568'],
            labels: ['new', 're'],
            
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getByVisitor()
    },
    methods: {
     getByVisitor() {
      const url = 'url';
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then(response => {
          this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{
            name: 'Sales',
            data: response.data
          }])
        })
        .catch(error => (this.byVisitor = error.data));
        console.log(`---------------this.$refs.chart1`, this.$refs.chart1);
    },
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have a `series` data property which you're attempting to use in `:series="series"`

Comment: @Phil I coded it, but did not write here when I was writing, but even with it, it gives me `undefined`

Comment: I don't know, what do the `apexchart` docs say? Also, refs won't be populated until the `mounted` hook has completed so trying to access `this.$refs.chart1` might not work if being called from within `created` (depending on how fast the request resolves)

Comment: I suggest you read the [docs on how to update data](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/#updating-series). You should only need to populate `series` rather than trying to call methods on the chart component. If you do that, you can keep using the `created` hook

Comment: @Phil Oh, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474411/apexchart-does-not-update-dynamically-using-axios

And yes, I have read that docs, but that does not apply to my situation as I want to use `axios`

Comment: You can still use Axios, you just need to update your `series` array instead of calling `updateSeries()` on the component

Comment: @Phil Mmmkay.. so I really have no idea how to insert data in `series`..

Answer (score 0):

See [Updating Vue Chart Data](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/#updating-series)

There's no need to directly call the `updateSeries()` method on the chart component since it is able to react to changes in `series`. All you have to do is update your `series` data property

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    series: [], //  start with an empty array here
    byVisitor: null, //  you seem to have missed this one for your error data
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        type: 'donut',
      },
      colors: ['#01cd49', '#007568'],
      labels: ['new', 're'],
    }
  }),
  created: function() {
    this.getByVisitor()
  },
  methods: {
    async getByVisitor() {
      const url = 'url';
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    
        // now update "series"
        this.series = [{
          name: "Sales",
          data
        }]
      } catch (error) {
        this.byVisitor = error.data
      }
    },
  }
}
```